# Can't grepl be used in Apply function?

Tags: r, lapply, grepl

I have a dataframe with values as below:

```
BrandName  Expense
Apple      $1.8B
Google     $3.2B
GE         -
facebook   $281M
McDonald   $719M
```

I want to clean these expense values such that they are finally on same scale (in billions). For ex the final data frame should look like:

```
BrandName  Expense
Apple      1.8
Google     3.2
facebook   0.281
McDonald   0.719
```

$ can be simply removed by gsub. This is fine. But I am facing problem afterwards.
I am applying a function A which uses grepl to check if the value contains 'M', if true (strip 'M', convert to numeric value, and divide by 1000)
and if it returns false (strip 'B', convert to numeric value)

```
A <- function(x){
  if (grepl("M", x))
  {
    str_replace(x, "M", "")
    as.numeric(x)
    x <- x/1000
  }
  else if (grepl("B", x))
  {
    str_replace(x, "B", "")
    as.numeric(x)
  }
}
frame <- data.frame(frame[1], apply(frame[2],2, A))
```

But all the expense values are coming out to be NA in final result. 
On further analysis, I noticed for all values, its going in elseif part.
Am i making a bad use of grepl in apply function ? If yes how can i fix it.

or any other better solution to solve this particular problem?

Comment: @akrun: The question you suggested is exactly opposite to what I asked.

Comment: In your function, you should assign the returned values of `str_replace` and `as.numeric` to `x`.  In addition, `apply(frame[2], 2, A)` applies `grepl` to the entire column (i.e. a vector of strings), which is why you might have gotten the `the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used` warning.  You should `apply` by rows, i.e. `apply(frame[2], MAR = 1, A)` or use `sapply`.  This is why `grepl` isn't working as you expect.

Comment: @WeihuangWong: Thank you for pointing out my mistakes, you got a point! I will check if it works once I fix the problems mentioned by you. Thanks once again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a base R solution which might be more sensible for your problem, depending on your needs:

```
df$ExpenseScaled <- as.numeric(gsub("[$MB]", "", df$Expense))
m.index          <- substr(df$Expense, nchar(df$Expense), nchar(df$Expense)) == 'M'
df$ExpenseScaled[m.index] <- df$ExpenseScaled[m.index] / 1000

 df
 BrandName Expense ExpenseScaled
1     Apple   $1.8B         1.800
2    Google   $3.2B         3.200
3  Facebook   $281M         0.281
4 McDonalds   $719M         0.719
```

The first line of code removes the dollar sign and amount symbol (`B` or `M`) to obtain a numerical amount.  The next two lines of code conditionally divide millions figures by 1000 per your specification.

Comment: @cexplorer Sorry, I had a typo in there.  I meant to use `m.index` to subset the `ExpenseScaled` column.  Try it again, it just worked for me.

Comment: Perfect! I think this is the most elegant solution to my problem. Just out of curiosity what was wrong in the solution I was trying. I know there would be multiple problems ;)

Comment: @cexplorer I see multiple problems indeed, such as you calling `as.numeric(x)`.  This won't actually _set_ the `x` variable to be numeric.  To do that, you would need an _assignment_, e.g. `x <- as.numeric(x)`.  Also, there appear to be problems in the way you were trying to rollup data in your custom function.  I don't think you need a custom function to handle this problem.

Comment: yeah that silly mistake I noticed. But why grepl in first case always returned false ? Why was it always going in the other grep ? Any idea

Comment: @cexplorer I'm not convinced that it always went to the `else` condition.  I think some other problems were happening.

Comment: OP: See my comment to your question above. The problem is that you are `apply`ing column-wise.

Answer (score 0):

We can do this with `gsubfn`.  We remove the `$` with `sub`, then replace the 'B', and 'M' with `1` and `* 1/1000` using `gsubfn`, loop through the `vector` and evaluate the string.

```
library(gsubfn)
df1$Expense <-  unname(sapply(gsubfn("([A-Z])$", list(B=1, M=' * 1/1000'), 
          sub("[$]", "", df1$Expense)), function(x) eval(parse(text=x))))
df1
#   BrandName Expense
#1     Apple   1.810
#2    Google   3.210
#3  facebook   0.281
#4  McDonald   0.719
```

---

Or a `base R` option would be to extract the numeric substring ('val'), the substring at the end ('nm1'), convert the 'val' to numeric and multiply with the 1, 1/1000 based on matching the substring 'nm1' with the key/value' string created.

```
val <- gsub("[^0-9.]+", "", df1$Expense)
nm1 <- sub(".*(.)$", "\\1", df1$Expense)
df1$Expense <-  as.numeric(val)*setNames(c(1, 1/1000), c("B", "M"))[nm1]
df1
#  BrandName Expense
#1     Apple   1.800
#2    Google   3.200
#3  facebook   0.281
#4  McDonald   0.719
```

NOTE: This should be also be extended in case there are Trillions, Thousands etc. in both the methods, i.e. in the first method change inside the `list(...)` and in second we change by creating more key/value groups in `setNames(c(1, ...), c("B", "M", ...))`

---

Another option is `parse_number` from `readr` with `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
library(readr)
df1 %>% 
   mutate(Expense = parse_number(Expense)/c(1, 1000)[grepl("M", Expense)+1])
#   BrandName Expense
#1     Apple   1.800
#2    Google   3.200
#3  facebook   0.281
#4  McDonald   0.719
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(BrandName = c("Apple", "Google", "facebook", "McDonald"
), Expense = c("$1.8B", "$3.2B", "$281M", "$719M")), .Names = c("BrandName", 
"Expense"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -4L))
```

Comment: Its working on sample, but giving error on my data.  Error in parse(text = x) : <text>:2:0: unexpected end of input
1: -
   ^  I forgot to mention there are missing values in form of "-" in expense column. Is that the reason why its not working on my dataset.?

Comment: @cexplorer I also updated with another option. Please check if that also give the same problem.